# How can I implement increment counter in my case?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a mobile app using flutter for getting feedback from the student about the teacher.
I have 4 questions of my own and each question have 4 options.I am storing the vote count for each option of each question.
When any teacher register in our app we set all the counts to zero.

```
'feedback':{
        '1' : [0,0,0,0],
        '2' : [0,0,0,0],
        '3' : [0,0,0,0],
        '4' : [0,0,0,0],
      }
```

Now when any student will give feedback about any teacher the count of the options which that students have selected will get incremented by one.
(example : In the same way as Instagram show the vote on each option for any questions in story.)

I am using cloud function to increment the value but I'm stuck I don't know how to proceed in my case.

for example : Student X selected option for question is - 1:3 , 2:1 , 3:2 , 4:4
I know which index count I have to increment but guide me how to do this.

```
    exports.feedback = function.https.onCall((data,context) => {
        const teacher = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.tID);
        const student = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.sID);
        return teacher.get().then(doc => {
            const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
            

//help me on this line

    batch.set(teacher,{feedback : '1':[,,admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),,]}). 
       


 });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the value of an array inside a document, you will have to:

1. Read the document
2. Modify the array in memory to be the way you want
3. Write the array back to the document

The way you are using `FieldValue.increment()` right now just won't work as an item in an array.

Comment: But what iif someone will try to give feedback at the same time.

Comment: You an use a transaction for an atomic read-then-write operation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions